# el metodo nextInt de Scanner me pide doble dato, cuando en el codigo solo especifica uno

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la aplicacion consiste que el usuario debe ingresar una cantidad, el cual sera usado para disminuir un numero. El problema se da durante la ejecucion, en la instrucion de pedir la cantidad al usuario o precionar ctrl + z, el programa pide dos enteros para seguir con la ejecucion en vez de uno.

Comment: Pon el código en texto en lugar de imágenes.

Answer (score -1):

El problema con tu código está en usar el `hasNext()`, ese método retorna true si hay un nuevo token para leer pero bloquea el escaner.

Lo que está pasando es lo siguiente:

1. `cantidad = entrada.nextInt();` Se lee el numero ingresado y se guarda en cantidad.
2. `while (entrada.hasNext())` bloquea el escaner esperando que haya un nuevo token, por eso te pide ingresar otro número. Cuando lo ingresas retorna true y se repite la iteración volviendo al paso 1.

Puedes cambiar el `do while` por un `while` y funciona bien:

```
       boolean seguir = true;
        while(seguir){
            numero -= cantidad;
            System.out.println("cantidad a disminuir: " + cantidad);
            System.out.println("valor actual del numero: " + numero + "\n");
            System.out.print("escribe la cantidad a disminuir o ctr + z para terminar: ");
            cantidad = entrada.nextInt();
        }
```